# Determining convergence/ divergence using root/ratio test: $\sum \frac1{(\log(n))^{1/n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am having trouble determining convergence/ divergence of the following series:

$\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\log(n))^{1/n}}$

When I apply the root and ratio tests, I find in both cases the limit 1 (which means that the test is inconclusive).

Please help

Comment: Hint: What is $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \bigl(\log (n)\bigr)^{1/n}$?

Answer (score 2):

Just use the [limit test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LimitTest.html). It is $\log(n)^{1/n}\longrightarrow 1\neq 0$, so the series cannot converge.

Comment: The limit test states that if $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=1$ and $\sum b_n$ converges then $\sum a_n$ converges. How did you use it here?

Comment: @user43758 He is not referring to that test, but rather the following: If $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n\ne 0$, then the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ diverges.

Comment: @DavidMitra note that's actually the contrapositive of the usual theorem that's taught ($\sum a_n$ converges $\implies a_n \to 0$).

Answer (score 0):

We can use the fact that if $a_n>0$ for all $n\ge1$ and the sequence $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ converges in $[0,\infty]$, then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}
$$
(see this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724448/proof-of-lim-n-to-infty-a-n1-n-lim-n-to-inftya-n1-a-n)).

We have that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\biggl(\frac1{\log n}\biggr)^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac1{\log(n+1)}}{\frac1{\log n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log n}{\log n+\log(1+1/n)}=1.
$$
Hence, the series diverges.