# $\lim_{n\to \infty} {\sqrt[n]{n^{-n}+2^n}}$?

Tags: limits, infinity

$\lim_{n\to \infty} {\sqrt[n]{n^{-n}+2^n}}$

Intuitively, this seems like it should equal 2, but how would one go about showing this? I have tried factoring this somehow, but whatever form I get it in has some type of addition in the radicand. What other techniques could I use?

Comment: Write it as $\lim_{n\to\infty} 2 (1+(2/n)^n)^{1/n}$.

Comment: Do you know about continuity? All of the maps here are continuous for $n>0$.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith, you mean $\lim_{n\to\infty} 2(1+(1/(2n))^n)^{1/n}$, right?  Once it is expressed in this manner, then the limit is clearly 2 (you can use a trick with the natural logarithm if you want).

Comment: @NicholasStull Oops, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

$$2^n \leq n^{-n}+2^n \leq 2^{n+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

We can use the fact that if $a_n>0$ for all $n\ge1$ and the sequence $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ converges in $[0,\infty]$, then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}
$$
(see this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724448/proof-of-lim-n-to-infty-a-n1-n-lim-n-to-inftya-n1-a-n)).

We have that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\biggl(\frac{(n+1)^{-(n+1)}+2^{n+1}}{n^{-n}+2^n}\biggr)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)^{-(n+1)}}{n^{-n}+2^n}+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac2{\frac{n^{-n}}{2^n}+1}=0+2
$$
and
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^{1/n}=2.
$$