# Limit of $\frac{2 \sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Why the limit of the following sequence is like this:

$$\frac{2 \sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}=\frac{2}{e}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use the fact that if $a_n>0$ for all $n\ge1$ and the sequence $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ converges in $[0,\infty]$, then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}
$$
(see this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724448/proof-of-lim-n-to-infty-a-n1-n-lim-n-to-inftya-n1-a-n)).

We have that $a_n=n!/n^n$ and
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)!n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}n!}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^n}=\frac1{\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+1/n)^n}=\frac1e.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: We have
$$\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}=(\frac{n!}{n^n})^{\frac{1}{n}}=(\frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{2}{n}\cdots\frac{n}{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
which implies that 
$$\log\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\log\frac{i}{n}.$$
By [Riemann sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum), we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\log\frac{i}{n}=\int_0^1\log x dx.$$
Using integration by parts, we can evaluate the last integral, which I just leave it to you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to use [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)?

For large values of $n$, $n!$ goes like $\sqrt{2\pi n} \left( \frac{n}{e} \right)^n$, so

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt[n]{\sqrt{2\pi n} \left( \frac{n}{e} \right)^n}}{n} = \ldots$$

Comment: no i even do not know the stirling approximation

Comment: Too bad, because it's quite easy (not to say trivial) if you could use it :-).

Comment: see that, thank you :)