# Convergence of sequence and sum.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Do the sequence $$\frac{n}{{n!}^{\frac{1}{n}}}$$ and the sum

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{{n!}^{\frac{1}{n}}}$$
converge?
And if they do converge then to what real number.
It seems to me that the sequence converges but I have no clue about the sum.

Comment: Use the Stirling formula for the factorial.

Comment: As part of your question, you should include what argument you use to convince yourself that the sequence converges.

Comment: @marmouset : Overhard in this problem.

Comment: The first sequence converges to $e \neq 0$, so that the series is divergent.

Comment: Hint: Note that $n! \leq n^n$.

Comment: actually Stirling is a very bad idea, I was even planning to put an exposant 1/n on it

Comment: @marmouset I tried using Stirling's formula but no use.

Comment: @marmouset: can you elaborate ?

Comment: Proving the convergence of the expression I got by Stirling's formula seemed harder than the original problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use the fact that if $a_n>0$ for all $n\ge1$ and the sequence $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ converges in $[0,\infty]$, then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}
$$
(see this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724448/proof-of-lim-n-to-infty-a-n1-n-lim-n-to-inftya-n1-a-n)).

We have that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\biggl(\frac{n^n}{n!}\biggr)^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}n!}{(n+1)!n^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\biggl(1+\frac1{n}\biggr)^n=e.
$$
Hence, the sequence converges but the series diverges.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding just the sum, since you say you have a handle on the term by itself.

For $n>1$, we have $1 < n, 2 < n, \dots, n-1 < n$ and $n = n$, so $n! < n^n$.  Then $n!^{1/n} < (n^n)^{1/n} = n$.  So, for $n>1$,

> $$  \frac{n}{n!^{1/n}} > \frac{n}{n} = 1  $$

and the sum cannot converge because the terms do not go to zero.

Did you think the limiting value of the term was zero?

Comment: No ,I knew that the terms converged to some real numbers greater than 0, because I calculated the terms for n=1000.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the logarithm,

$$\log s_n=-\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\log\frac kn.$$

In the limit,

$$\log s_\infty=-\int_0^1\log x\,dx=1.$$